# Backslash to forwardslash on the Window

Tags: window

How can I change backslash to forwardslash on the Window.

Eg: change

```
C:\Users\chuan\Videos\Captures\abc
```

to

```
C:/Users/chuan/Videos/Captures/abc
```

I try to change `\` to `/` manually but it takes a lot of time.